# Duplicate project key in Sonarqube Server

Tags: sql-server, sonarqube

We are facing the following issue: we are unable to update project key in Sonar, error message is as following:
[Error 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rSF2D.png)
If I try to create one it will show me that Error has occurred without directly telling me that project with that key already exists.
[Error Creation](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5jQLU.png)

We did a search in the dbo.projects table of SQ and obviously nothing popped up (duh)
Also we looked through all the rest of the database and found that our dbo.components table contains some records that are evidence of the project with the name existed some time in the past.
We used the following query to get the results:
`select * FROM [SonarQube].[dbo].[components] where kee like "PROJECT_NAME"`

My questions are:
What are those components that are appearing in the output?
Can they be blocking us from creating new project?
If yes, can they safely be deleted?
If no, what else can you suggest to look into?